# Зачем делегаты в Unity? C#

Tags: c#, unity3d

В официальном мануале Unity есть такой пример делегатов

```
public class DelegateScript : MonoBehaviour 
{   
delegate void MyDelegate(int num);
MyDelegate myDelegate;


void Start () 
{
    myDelegate = PrintNum;
    myDelegate(50);

    myDelegate = DoubleNum;
    myDelegate(50);
}

void PrintNum(int num)
{
    print ("Print Num: " + num);
}

void DoubleNum(int num)
{
    print ("Double Num: " + num * 2);
}
```

Не совсем понятно - ведь такой вывод мы можем получить элементарным

```
 void Start () 
{
    PrintNum(50);
    DoubleNum(50);
}
```

Объясните пожалуйста, зачем они тут и нужны ли они в таких ситуациях вообще;

Comment: К примеру ты хочешь в зависимости от условий вызвать только одну из функций, а в зависимости от других другую.  Поэтому где то(например в Update) ты можешь написать myDelegate(50) а он вызовет именно нужную функцию(ту которую ты присвоил ему в условии).  А вообще хорошо бы ссылку на страницу, а то мало ли  о чем  там написано...

Comment: https://unity3d.com/ru/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/delegates
Т.е. я правильно понял, что делегаты в данном случае выполняют роль аналогичную геттерам и сеттерам - подразумевается что они являются как бы прослойкой между методом и тем, что к нему обращается. И в это прослойку можно вписать свои условия. Верно?

Comment: нет. Просто они показали возможности, а как ими пользоваться твое дело.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

По той же причине, по которой они есть в C#.

Можно почитать MSDN и понять их нужность и зачем они были придуманы.

**Вкратце:**

Делегат- это удобная обертка над указателями на функции, которые есть в С++.

Например, можно сделать одним из аргументов метода делегат.

При вызове методы, мы передаем в метод делегат, который указывает на нужную функцию, а внутри метода мы можем вызвать этот делегат.

Делегаты используются так же в событиях.

**UPD**

И вообще Unity использует все языковые возможности C# и очевидно, что почти весь функционал доступен в Unity.

А использовать или не использовать всю возможность языка решать вам.

С таким же успехом вы можете, как использовать лаконичные возможности 
`LINQ`, которые сами в `IL` коде сгенерируют необходимый код, а можете и сами использовать `foreach` и итерировать коллекции, но это будет несколько менее лаконично...

Т.е язык дает вам возможности, а распоряжаетесь ими вы.